# Converting from a double to a String but keeping an leading zeros

Tags: java, string, excel, parsing, double

I am trying to convert from a double to a String. It is working but it is removing all leading zeros. For example, 00010000 is being changed to 10000 and 01 is changed to 1. I am trying to read an xls file and it is proving difficult.

The amount of digits is not known when running the program so I couldn't think of a way to get around this problem. Could anyone help?

Below is my code:

```
while (cells.hasNext()) {
          cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
          if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
            lineList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
          } else if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            String s = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            lineList.add(s);
          }
        }
```

Comment: is this a `double` number? 00010000??

Comment: There's no such concept as a leading 0 in a `double` (or any other numeric type in Java).

Comment: You could use `String.format` to set the width and precision with leading zeros for padding when you convert to String in Java.

Answer (score 0):

My guess as to what is happening here is that you have numeric data in Excel which is formatted as `00010000`.  However, internally in Excel this data is probably just stored as `10000` or `10000.0` etc. and the leading zeroes are just present because of your formatting.  When you imported this numeric data into Java using `HSSF`, it also came in as `10000` or `10000.0` etc.  As others have already mentioned, there are no "leading" zeroes in a Java `double` primitive type.  So when you convert to a `String`, of course there are no leading zeroes, because they simply don't exist.

**Possible workaround:**

If you format your Excel numeric column as text, and then import it, then the following `if` condition should fire for these values:

```
if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
    lineList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
}
```

You can then simply read in the text values directly, leading zeroes and all, and retain the information which was present in your Excel spreadsheet.

I have not tested this, but this would probably be something I would try if I were faced with your problem.